# Listing of vim options by context, not alphabetical

Tags: vim, neovim

When I do `:help options`, it gives me an alphabetical list of all options that can be used with `set`. However, it is hard to tell which options are for which context.

Is there any documentation out there that shows vim options sorted by context, like display, paths/cwd, shortcuts, etcetera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No list is authoritative, but you may want have a look at `:options` command. It creates a temporary "interactive" buffer with many options / descriptions / values sorted by topic.

Comment: @filbranden BTW. It's implemented in VimScript; the code is in `$VIMRUNTIME/optwin.vim`